# How to restart activity with data of previous or next position of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, restart

I'm building a book reader app and currently having some issues on how to move to next or previous chapter.

The fragment that is in charge of showing a list of chapter (basically a ListView). I capture the item with onItemClick:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ReaderActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",adapter.getItem(i).getName());
            intent.putExtra("url",adapter.getItem(i).getUrl());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
});
```

It will start the `ReaderActivity` and display the content of the book. Now the `ReaderActivity` has 2 buttons for moving to next/previous chapter. How can I get the data (the `name` and `url`) from the ListView?

At the moment I'm thinking of two methods:

1. Calling `finish()` on `ReaderActivity` and override the `onDestroy()` method to call a method to get the next/previous data in the fragment that holds the ListView.
2. Passing the whole ArrayList of chapters to `ReaderActivity` so it can retrieve the item it wants (probably not a good solution since there are too many chapters).

Is there a better way?

Comment: or you can store chapter list to internal storage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are way to many ways to get the best one.

Some of them:

1. Use your `Application.java` to share in-memory data (data stores) from any place. Example:

   ```
   public final Application extends android.app.Application {
       private List<Chapter> chapters;

       public void setChapters(List<Chapter> chapters) {
           this.chapters = chapters != null ? chapters : Collections.<Chapter>epmtyList();
       }

       public List<Chapter> get Chapters() {
           return chapters;
       }
   }

   // from any place which has context (or is context)
   List<Chapter> chapters = ((Application) getContext().getApplicationContext()).getChapters();
   ```
2. Make your list a static member with a public static getter and then reference is from your `ReaderActivity`

   ```
   public final ApplicationActivity extends Activity {
       private static List<Chapter> chapters;

       ....

       public static List<Chapter> getChapters() {
           return chapters;
   }
   ```
3. Store the list in shared preferences so any activity can reference it
4. Include the list of chapters in your intent extras and pass it to your `ReaderActivity`

I think your `ReaderActivity` needs to deal with the whole book rather a single chapter. Which means approach (4) is most likely a good candidate.

Comment: I end up going with the fourth approach. I have my object implemented the Parcelable interface and passed it to the `ReaderActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the list data in the Application class (or another singleton), and then the ReaderActivity would be able to query it for the next chapter. Actually then it could just get the details of the next chapter and update its contents accordingly, without needing to create a new activity at all.

Comment: But there are also many books. I'm thinking of using Parcelable to pass the chapters (about 500-900) to the `ReaderActivity`. I don't know whether it's gonna take some time.